# Has Orion's touch-screen instrument panel been influenced by Dragon's v2 panel? (or vice-versa)

Tags: spacex, orion-spacecraft, dragon

I recently read about Orion's touch-screen instrument panels designs, and remember seeing this first on the Dragon v2 unveiling (with a 4 panel design instead of 3).

Was this design influenced in any way by one or the other? (Dragon influencing Orion's, or vice-versa)

Comment: NASA had been working on Orion for long time. So no dragon could not have inspired it. Rather I read somewhere that they got this idea from Boeing. Further you can check this ["NASA's New Spacecraft Will Have A Star Trek-Like Cockpit"](http://www.io9.com/nasas-new-spacecraft-will-have-a-star-trek-like-cockpit-1613903846) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More likely the Dragon interface was influenced by the Tesla car interface. The Tesla Model S has a 17 inch touch screen that contains almost all of the cars controls. It is designed to be used while driving, with minor accelerations, compared to space launch. But this is much more concern than the common touch interface of a phone or tablet.

The Orion team and the SpaceX team have been nicely isolated and unlikely to have influenced each other. But they both looked at the state of the art today, looked at their options and made decisions.

Comment: Sounds fair, I guess both arrived to the same conclusion and benefits of the design outweigh the disadvantages (if any). It also makes sense Tesla's interface might have had an influence on Dragon's, given the close relationship of both.
Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

Nikets comment is correct, the Orion glass cockpit has been in development since its 'go ahead' in 2004.

Geoffc's answer is also correct in that the SpaceX team has a very different way of looking at the glass cockpit.

As WhiteLancer64 answers, by comparison, both Orion and Boeing's Starliner share closer links with the aviation industry. Whilst SpaceX went with all touch screen interface, Orion (and even more so for Starliner) do not use touch screens per se.

So, OP's question of:

> Has Orion's touch-screen instrument panel been influenced by Dragon's v2 panel? (or vice-versa)

*Answer is no, in both cases; and that Orion (and Starliner) display panels have **much stronger ties to the aviation industry**.*

TL;DR:

On Orion's glass cockpit unveil in 2014, a lot of it was also compared to the aviation industry - the screens are from Honeywell, commonly used in aircraft, and technology from both Boeings 777 and 787 was oft mentioned in press releases.

Anyone who has worked in the aviation industry would immediately recognise the type of edge screen key technology employed in the Orion cockpit, with units such as these common in both the civil and military aviation industry:

[image]

When Starliners glass cockpit display was unveiled it was much less glass and even more old school, but with MFD's, rather like current aircraft. They also openly mentioned being influenced by the Orion cockpit display.

Overview of Orions glass cockpit:

[image]

> The displays can show relevant
> information to the crew, such as data pertaining to vehicle
> systems, propulsion systems, and electrical systems.
>
> One
> **navigates between these displays by using the edge keys**,
> which are the grey rectangular buttons, surrounding
> the Display Unit (DU).

> These displays can also be used to
> change settings to the aforementioned systems and to also
> display electronic procedures (eProc). The electronic procedure
> system “assists crew members by highlighting vehicle states on
> a display and cueing up appropriate displays, pop-ups, and
> commands”. In addition, eProc is “linked to fault
> messages, so that crew members can quickly access procedures
> to any message that appears on the fault summary or log
> displays” . Thus, eProc allows the crew to rapidly assess an
> emergency scenario and enact the proper steps to rectify the
> situation. The advantage of eProc is that it supplants hardcopy
> manuals, resulting in a reduction of launch weight by the order
> of hundreds of pounds as no printed material needs to be
> brought onboard. A crewmember can access the eProc display
> to pull up an onscreen operations manual that can walk the user
> through the various stages of the mission.

> 

There are **three main forms of crew interaction** with the
display: a **cursor control device** (CCD), a **cursor knob** (also
known as a “twizzle”), or **edge key presses** that traverse
through selectable elements on the screen.

> **Pressing edge keys
> is the most direct method of control**

The
CCD is to the pilot’s left and complements the joystick. On the
CCD are several buttons, a bidirectional rocker switch, and “a
four-way ‘caged’ castle switch on the CCD … designed to travel
only to controllable elements toward decreasing erroneous cursor movements”. The switches allow the user to
transfer between the various displays and popups.

> Popups are the menus that appear onscreen when certain
> selections are made within the displays. For example, when the
> user is in the Main Propulsion System (MPS) display, a popup
> appears when the edge key is selected for “Engine Shutdown”.
> This popup has one enumeration, or choice, which allows the
> user to shutdown a given engine.

Screen template:

[image]

[image]

> After 10 years of evolution, the prototypes of NASA’s Orion “glass cockpit” are finally reaching maturity.

> Morin said that NASA engineers considered a wide variety of alternatives before settling on the current shape. “We had things that looked like motorcycle grips and **Klingon battle swords**,” he said. “There were some pretty wild-looking designs, but we eventually gravitated toward the blob.”
>
> The current evolution of the glass cockpit uses three large DU-1310 screens from Honeywell International, Inc.
>
> The monitors are called a glass cockpit because most of the spacecraft’s instruments are represented as images on them. All but 56 of the 2,000 switches will be transformed into software icons.

https://www.designnews.com/aerospace/exclusive-closer-look-nasas-orion-glass-cockpit

> Orion uses a processor from 2003's Apple iBook G3, which is less powerful than a modern smartphone.
>
> The reason Orion is packed with this old technology... Orion has been on the drawing board in some form or other since 2004, so technologies employed on the spacecraft are likely to be from a similar time.
>
> Orion's flight computer uses a somewhat cumbersome console that was **first developed for Boeing airliners**. It is powered by two IBM PowerPC 750FX chips, a processor used in Apple machines up until 2005.

https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3462708/A-look-inside-Orion-Nasa-reveals-just-three-screens-used-control-spacecraft-humans-Mars.html

> the space agency is using a Honeywell International Inc. flight computer originally built for Boeing's 787 jet airliner.
>
> A lot of the technology on Orion came from either the airline industry or the U.S. military. For instance, the spacecraft's beacons and some of its antennas are based on technology that was first developed for the military.

https://www.computerworld.com/article/2855604/the-orion-spacecraft-is-no-smarter-than-your-phone.html

> NASA’s new Orion spaceship will fly with an ancient skeumorphic UI

> Apple users are familiar with skeuomorphism, a design principle in which elements of the design mimick the look and feel of physical objects, such as a desktop calendar or an old tape deck.
>
> It’s an easy way to introduce users to new digital interfaces: If the new interface looks like a familiar object from the physical world, it’s immediately obvious how it works.
>
> Skeuomorphism was one of the favored design principals at Apple until about a year after Steve Jobs’ death.
>
> Orion’s control panels simulate dozens of manual buttons across three screens. That’s a huge improvement on the space shuttle cockpit, which had about 2,000 physical buttons and switches across 10 panels.
>
> NASA calls the new UI a “glass” interface, because the manual controls are simulated on computer screens. However, the **Orion control panels are not touchscreens** — for good reason:
>
> Objects floating in space could knock against the screen and set off an undesired action, he warns. Also, the controls need to be worked by fingers that are often covered in thick spacesuit gloves.
>
> **To operate the glass interface’s virtual buttons and switches, astronauts must rely on a series of edge buttons**, which help them to quickly scroll through screens.

https://www.cultofmac.com/305280/nasa-orion-spaceship-skeumorphic-ui/

> NASA Orion crew vehicle will use voice controls in **Boeing 787-style Honeywell smart cockpit**

> The Lockheed Martin-built Orion will use a glass cockpit that is **derived from Honeywell's Boeing 787 flight deck technology**. Orion’s cockpit computers will carry out routine and repetitive system monitoring tasks, which Apollo-era astronauts had to do themselves.

https://www.flightglobal.com/nasa-orion-crew-vehicle-will-use-voice-controls-in-boeing-787-style-honeywell-smart-cockpit/69935.article

> **Orion’s computer system and “glass cockpit” is modeled after the Boeing 777 design**. NASA reuses this existing, flight-tested aircraft system to be cost-effective, which makes sense and aids in remaining within budget constraints, while still maintaining safety and functionality for astronauts in space.

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/glass-cockpit-display-technologies-space-shuttles/

> "The Orion has maybe 30 switches in the cockpit; all the rest of it is electronic digital controls.
>
> "You'll have a screen with a representation of the system you're controlling with valves and power switches ... You can highlight the item you want to command, press a button; a little window pops up with a list of commands, you select the command you want, and send it off to the vehicle."

https://www.space.com/artemis-orion-spacecraft-digital-age-cockpit

> **If it’s good enough for a Boeing 787, it’s gotta be good enough for space, right?**

> a “glass cockpit” that will make it easier for astronauts to step across the Solar System, based on the passenger jet avionics.

https://www.csmonitor.com/Science/2014/1202/How-will-astronauts-control-the-Orion-spaceship

Starliner vs Spacex:

> The two corporations have been working in parallel, yet their approaches — and designs — are strikingly different.

> Panels of gauges, switches, monitors, and number pads take up most of the astronaut's view. A joystick allows for more precise inputs. It's a design far more reminiscent of NASA's Space Shuttle's cockpit — more commercial airliner than Tesla.

https://futurism.com/boeings-spaceship-cockpit-looks-strikingly-different-spacexs

> Boeing’s Ferguson on Starliner – no touch screens, but far simpler than Shuttle

> “The way you interact with the screen is actually, **we borrowed a little bit from Orion**, and it’s kind of **the way some of the 5th generation military planes interact with pilots**,”
>
> “In the corner of the display, we call it a twizzle, is the way you register your way through all the fields you can interact with on the screen.  And there are also bezel buttons that enable you to interact with the vehicle as well.”
>
> “So no touchscreen.  We interact in a very Orion-like way.  And the switches you do see are really so that if you absolutely have to do something and don’t have time to navigate your way through levels of displays, they’re right there for you,”

https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2018/08/boeing-starliner-crew-spacecraft/

> Despite being in an age of touch-screen phones and tablets, the displays are **only operated using switches on the side of the board** to prevent astronauts in zero gravity from accidentally triggering the screen.

https://www.tampabay.com/news/clearwater/2023/05/23/clearwater-nasa-artemis-orion-cockpit-honeywell-aerospace-moon-astronauts/

NASA cockpit unveil, 2014:

Links:

https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/491544main_orion_book_web.pdf

https://aerospaceapplications-na.com/#spacecraft-display-prototyping

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20160011222/downloads/20160011222.pdf

https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20170007938/downloads/20170007938.pdf

https://www.honeywell.com/us/en/press/2022/11/honeywell-proudly-supports-nasa-s-artemis-i-launch-and-orion-spacecraft-with-key-technologies-to-bring-humans-to-the-moon-and-mars

https://www.honeywell.com/us/en/press/2020/01/honeywell-and-lockheed-martin-to-provide-critical-components-for-nasas-orion-spacecraft

Note:

NASA also partners with airlines to observe operations and test concepts in the cockpit.

https://www.nasa.gov/feature/langley/nasa-works-with-airline-to-improve-pilot-training-and-cockpit-displays

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Orion's control panel displays aren't touchscreens, they are similar to the control panel displays on airplanes with buttons along the edges that can be pressed to select options on the screen. However, there will be touchscreen tablets onboard with checklists and for other crew use, much like are used on the Dragon. NASA's promo materials have proudly said that the gloves on the Orion's orange IVA suits are touch-screen compatible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).